# Can singularity screw up your model?

Tags: finite-element, numerical-modelling

I've been running some complicated Finite Element Models. In most cases, the stress repartition seemed to be absolutely correct. However, on several point (complicated geometry), it appears that stress is way beyond the overall stress in that area.

The same goes for calculus of hydrostatic pressure. While all the model ranges between -150;150 kPa, there are some areas that reach the insane values of 300 or even 1MPa.

How can I be sure the singularities in those points does not alter stress repartition to a point where the model is not realistic ?

Comment: @BillBarth already answer your question. I will add that geometric discontinuities like corners or sharp holes are locations where stresses are concentrated (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_concentration).

Answer (score 4):

Yes!

Any reentrant corner has a singularity at the corner (thus the classic L-shaped domain problem). There's lots of literature on this, but I don't know that it's a completely solved problem.

Comment: Thank you ! So... _How can I be sure the singularities in those points does not alter stress repartition to a point where the model is not realistic ?_

Comment: It does alter the stress. You need to do some research on methods for reentrant corners in structures analysis. I can't lay out the whole thing for you here.